# Left floating content in horizontally layout without fixed width

Tags: html, css

I am helping a friend building her website. I myself am half-way amateur when it comes to webdesign, resulting in countless frustrations usually resolved by hours of google-searching. But not this time. I really tried hard to find an already existing answer without any useable solution.

To the point: [Here's a working example of how far I have got yet](http://lvdbc.dk/egebro.html)

Each letter in the 'menu' represents a piece of work, clicking them toggles project-divs containing pictures/slides.

- I want all the project-divs to arrange themself horizontal without wrapping to the lower line. This is working with my current constellation.
- I want the activated projects to float/align themself to the left (as much as their container-div allows them). This is only working partly:

  When 'A' is toggled, the first project pops up nice and aligns itself to the left. When 'B' subsequently is toggled, it also, nicely, aligns itself to the left, leaning up against project-'A'. The same goes for toggling 'C' + 'D' succeedingly.

  The problem starts when you toggle, say, 'D', as the first choice: here you'll get more white space to the left of the project than expected. Also toggling 'A' then 'D' you'll get a strange white space between the to projects - not anything I expect or want.

Any help from you guys?

Comment: Where's the JavaScript for `toggleDiv`?

Comment: Hay! I've just added the whole HTML - including the jQuery .toggle(DivId) function. Any thoughts?

Comment: Why not just display all of the images at once, and use the left side as a way to navigate through the images?

Comment: Hay Wex. Thats a possibility, but it's not what I'm looking for, since I'm hooked on the toggle-function.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the following styles to the '.child' element:

```
.child{
  float:left;
  margin-right:10px;
  display: inline-block;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

and give the parent div (#parent) a width each time an item is toggled. So every time an item is added, it's width gets added to the width of #parent, allowing the horizontal scroll.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi Sagar, Thanks for helping out. Since my knowledge of coding is very limited, I don't quite know where to go from now. I guess adding some lines of jQuery to the existing toggle function targeting the parent div?

Comment: Add the float:left and the margin-right:10px to .child first and see if it helps. The '10px' for the margin-right is a test value and you can change the same to a value of your choice. For testing, add a width of 10000px to '#parent' to test if the scrolling is working. What needs to happen is that each time a '.child' element is displayed, the width of the horizontal div needs to expand accordingly to accommodate the new '.child' elements. Let me know if it works.

Comment: This works. Now the projects aligns them self horizontally without wrapping to the next line. But, of course, when the projects become activated, exceeding the screen-size, the scroll-x pops up with a width of 10000px and not the width of the total nr of projects/children+margin. Thanks again!

Comment: I've created a fiddle explaining the code - http://jsfiddle.net/hgZD6/1/. I've also made a dummy menu highlighting how it should be structured. I noticed that you had multiple document.ready() calls and so I clubbed them all into a single call, along with the function to toggle boxes. This code is a little rough so you'll have to test it but it should work. I've added comments to explain the code. You'll have to adapt it for your requirements though I've tried to keep it as basic as possible.

Comment: Hi agian Patil, thanks for your patience and time. I've tried implementing the code, but my editor, says that there is a syntax error in the following line: `parent_width = $(box_id).hasClass('sel') : $('#parent').width() - box_width ? $('#parent').width() + box_width;` Any ideas?